# Is there anyway to view data from Firestore in graph or chart forms?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to retrieve data from my Cloud Firestore database but I am just wondering if there is anyway to display this data in a variety of forms. i.e a bar chart or in a pie chart for example?

Comment: Google a library. Check [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, actually there are a few different graphing libraries that are available for Android.

For one of my apps, I'm currently live-plotting sensor data using [Android GraphView](http://www.android-graphview.org/). It is quite customizable and it runs nice and smoothly. The video on the site looks basic, but you can change it the way it looks like to fit your design.

There is also another alternative named [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). It looks very good and is quite customizable, does also support live graphing. I've tested that and I recommend it. It has good documentation.